# Correct way to extend a class so I can override equals()

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class in a package that I cannot alter. This class does not override Object.equals() and having a different implementation of equals would really make my code cleaner.

I know I can't do this:

```
MyClass extends OtherClass{
@Override
public boolean equals(MyClass that)
{
//compare members and other stuff here
}
}

OtherClass oc1 = new OtherClass();
OtherClass oc2 = new OtherClass();
oc1.equals(oc2); //false because of Object.equals
//I want to do something like the following
MyClass mc1 = (MyClass) oc1; //throws class cast exception
MyClass mc2 = (MyClass) oc2; //throws class cast exception
mc1.equals(mc2); //true
```

What is the right way to accomplish this?

I could write a method like equals(OtherClass oc1, OtherClass oc2) but this is less useful. If I can implement equals I can make use of things like List.contains or Sets to manage my data and make life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a wrapper class?

```
MyWrapper {
    private OtherClass data;

    MyWrapper(OtherClass data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Add getter for stored object, if necessary.

Comment: @Freiheit Yes, `equals` will do whatever you program it to do.

Comment: @James Also -1 for not making constructor public and another -1 for not telling **Freiheit** to look on the left when he crosses the street :) I just answer a given question basing on given code sample, I'm not a step-by-step guidebook or manual for dummies.

Comment: I'm just saying, the code sample you gave is wrong without having hashCode.

Answer (score 1):

Do not override `equals` and not override `hashCode`.  Also, embrace Apache Commons lang, it provides many useful classes.  Using the Apache Commons `EqualsBuilder` and the Apache Commons `HashCodeBuilder`  classes Your class-that-provides-the-missing-equals-operation will look something like this:

```
public class NiceBerry extends NaughtyBerry
{
    public boolean equals(Object rhsObject)
    {
        if (rhsObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (rhsObject == this)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (rhsObject instanceof NiceBerry)
        {
            EqualsBuilder equalsBuilder = new EqualsBuilder();
            NiceBerry rhs = (NiceBerry)rhsObject;

            equalsBuilder.append(getField1(), rhs.getField1());
            equalsBuilder.append(getField2(), rhs.getField2());
            ... append all the naughty berry fields

            return equalsBuilder.isEquals();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        // you pick a hard-coded, randomly chosen, non-zero, odd number
        // ideally different for each class
        HashCodeBuilder hashBuilder = new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37);

        hashBuilder.append(getField1());
        hashBuilder.append(getField2());
        ... append all the naughty berry fields

        return hashBuilder.toHashCode();
    }
}
```